# Control doesn't enter the loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

I have a list of type Course. I'm using providers to add values to the list. While trying to store the data inside a map, control doesn't enter the loop. I was wondering what makes the control escape the loop. Really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

I have a model class for Course,

```
class Course {
  List<Map<String, List<String>>> list;
  Course(this.list);
}
```

Inside provider class,

```
  List<Course> _list = [];

  List<Course> get values => _list;

  void addValues(String coursename, String newValue) {
    // ! Control doesn't enter the loop
    values.map((course) {
      print('inside values.map');
      course.list.map((element) {
        element['$coursename'] = ['$newValue'];
        print('added map : $element');
      });
    }).toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Calling addValues

```
void clicked(String courseName, String newValue, BuildContext context) {
    if (newValue != null) {
      Provider.of<CourseProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .addValues(courseName, newValue);
    } 
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Dummy list for reference :

```
 List<Course> _list = [
    Course(
      list: [
       {
        'Morning_0': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
      },
      {
        'Evening_0': ['eee', 'fff', 'ggg']
      },
      ],
    ), //1
  ];
```

Comment: That usage of `map` is bizarre and very non-idiomatic in Dart, and I wouldn't be surprised if that was the source of your problems.

Comment: _list was empty while using `map`. Issue was resolved after populating data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using map function to iterate over the list to modify its content is error prone and should be avoided.** Also it creates new list instance for every `toList()` call which is not what you want. You should instead use standard looping methods like `forEach` or `for` loop for your use case. Following are the standard looping mechanisms available for dart language.

1. forEach
2. for loop
3. While
4. do-while

Check the language tour for [more details](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops).

---

**Well, you warned enough**, now here I explain the technical reason why your code did not work.

There are two reasons.

1. If the _list is empty initially, the first map function will not be called. So you need to make sure that your list is not empty before using map function.
2. You forgot to call `toList()` on `course.list.map`

> As long as the returned `Iterable` is not iterated over, the supplied function will not be invoked.

see the edited snippet below

```
 values.map((course) {
  print('inside values.map');
  course.list.map((element) {
    element['$coursename'] = ['$newValue'];
    print('added map : $element');
  }).toList();
}).toList();
```

Comment: This code reeks of `map` abuse. While you can use `map` to loop over elements in a collection, that's what `forEach` is for (or, indeed, a normal `for` or `for in` loop). Using `map` in this manner leads to quite unreadable code and the arbitrary generation of a list full of `null` values. This technically answers OP's question, but I'm sorely tempted to downvote it solely to discourage anyone from actually using this method of looping.

Comment: @Abion47 You are absolutely right, and i updated the answer.